# Semantic meaning of '36_864_7_345ms' as a time literal

Tags: syntax, system-verilog

Reading the spec for verilog, it appears that

```
36_864_7_345ms
```

Is a valid time literal: http://www.ece.uah.edu/~gaede/cpe526/SystemVerilog_3.1a.pdf (see section 2)

Note: decimal_digit is defined as `[0-9]` in the full IEEE spec.

What is the semantic meaning (if any) of this time literal? Or am I misreading the spec?

**Edit:**
Looking elsewhere in the spec (section 3.7.9), it appears that the underscore characters are silently discarded. Does the underscore act as an arbitrary seperating character in a similar way as numbers in English (ex. `43,251`) have commas to visually separate the numbers? Or is there another meaning altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec you quoted from is long since obsolete. Please get the [latest from the IEEE](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) where it says in section 5.7.1 Integer literal constants:

> The underscore character (_) shall be legal anywhere in a number
>   except as the first character. The underscore character is ignored.
>   This feature can be used to break up long numbers for readability
>   purposes.

Comment: I have the latest version of the spec, but I must have missed that section. I was trying to find a version that was publicly accessible to post.

Comment: The IEEE version is publicly accessible.

Comment: That's quite interesting. I had thought that was a paywall to see the spec, but apparently not.